# Splitting specific HTML tags in text up with PREG up into blocks

Tags: php, joomla

I'm trying to figure out whether this is at all possible in PHP.  I've wrote some code already that kind of achieves what I'm after, but it's quite a lot of code and I'm quite sure some kind of preg expression could possibly do something better as at present my code does a for loop through each letter of my text.

Here is an idea of what I'm trying to achieve, I've looked at numerous options but none seem to do exactly what I want, and most people say don't use PREG to parse HTML, I've also looked at DOM and SimpleXML but again these don't really give me the option I'm after either.

I'm using Joomla and K2 and Joomla/K2 is allowing me to put in a description in a field for a category.  Now I want to split that description up into three parts based on HTML tags.  Anything that is H1 I want in the $h1 variable, anything that is H2 in the $h2 variable and anything that is $p in the $p variable.  This also includes any sub tags so for example if I had the following html in the description

```
    <h1 class="title" >This title <b>with other tags</b></h1>
    <h2 class="someclass">secondary title <i>also with tags</i></h2>
    <p class="anotherclass" data-block="somedata">
    This is a text description <a href="#">with links</a> and more</p>
    <p>more P tags</p>
```

I did try simpleXML but that removed all the tags which wasn't what I wanted as I only wanted it split by either h1, h2 or p.  I thought PREG would work but am unsure how to make it work I know basically I need to possibly use something like preg_split and ask it to first retrieve <h1*</h1> (* being a wildcard but I know in preg * is not wildcard) and then the same with <h2*</h2> and <p*</p> at present this is the function I've got but it does seem a lot of code just to do a small thing

```
    function splitHtml ( $html ) 
    {
        $in_h2 = false ;
        $in_h1 = false ;
        $in_p = false ;
        $h1 = '' ;
        $h2 = '' ;
        $p = '' ;
        for ( $i = 0 ; $i < strlen ( $html ) ; $i++ )
        {
            if ( $html[$i] == '<' )
            {
                if ( $html[$i+1] == 'h' && $html[$i+2] == '2' )
                    $in_h2 = true ;
                if ( $html[$i+1] == 'h' && $html[$i+2] == '1' )
                    $in_h1 = true ;
                if ( $html[$i+1] == 'p' )
                    $in_p = true ;
                if ( $html[$i+1] == '/' )
                {              
                    if ( $html[$i+2] == 'h' && $html[$i+3] == '2' )
                    {
                       $in_h2 = false ;
                       $h2 .= '</h2>' ;
                    }
                    if ( $html[$i+2] == 'h' && $html[$i+3] == '1' )
                    {
                       $in_h1 = false ;
                       $h1 .= '</h1>' ;
                    }
                    if ( $html[$i+2] == 'p' )
                    {
                        $in_p = false ;
                        $p .= '</p>' ;
                    }
                }
            }
            if ( $in_h1 )
                $h1 .= $html[$i] ;
            if ( $in_h2 )
                $h2 .= $html[$i] ;
            if ( $in_p )
                $p .= $html[$i] ;
        }
        return ( array ( 'h1' => $h1, 'h2' => $h2, 'p' => $p ) ) ;
    }
```

Comment: Can you share your expected output?

Comment: my expected output is 
$h1 = '&lt;h1 class="someclass"&gt;Title&lt;b&gt;with tags&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/h1&gt;'  and the same for $p and $h2 with the relevant tags in each and if multiple tags occur then chain them together i.e. $h1 = '&lt;h1 class="someclass"&gt;Title&lt;b&gt;with tags&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/h1&gt;&lt;h1&gt;Another Title&lt;/h1&gt;'